# SpringMVC + Hibernate - Model Attribute & Updating

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to update some persistent object in user form.

My POJO Class:

```
public Class MyModel {
    int primKey;
    String value;
    // getter setter
}
```

Controller Methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEditView(@PathVariable int id, ModelMap model) {
        MyModel mymodel = modelService.getModel(id);
        model.addAttribute("mymodel", mymodel);
        return "/edit";
    }

@RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateModel(@ModelAttribute("mymodel") MyModel mymodel, HttpSession session) {
    session.setAttribute("status", modelService.update(mymodel) ? "success" : "error");
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

And my edit form:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="mymodel" role="form" method="post" action="/update">
<label>Enter new name:</label>
<form:input path="value"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Update" />
</form:form>
```

Now my question is when i receive model attribute "mymodel" in updateModel() method, "value" field is filled properly but "primKey" field is set to 0 which leads to failure in Hibernate Session's update method. Passing persistent object as "mymodel" makes it easier to display update form because all mapped values are set automatically and user can easily modify them. So is there any way to deal with this or i'll have to pass new MyModel attribute as model and update persistent object afterwards?

Comment: Are you sure, your `value` field is getting populated when you are loading (GET) update form and also submitting (POST) your form?

Comment: Yes it is. But it seems i'm getting totally new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `int primKey;` to `Integer primaryKey;`. By default int class variables are assigned 0, But Integer remains null.

I guess you want to auto generate the `primaryKey` and save an new record (`insert`). To do that `primaryKey` has to be `null`.

But since you are doing both the update and the insert in the same JSP template, you should have a hidden input binding for your `primaryKey`.

But if you feel like the primaryKey is sensitive data you can Encode the primaryKey and keep it as a hiddenValue and then send it back, and decode it and get the actual value and use it.

Answer (score 0):

`primKey` is `0` because you are using `int` instead of `Integer`.  `int` cannot be `null`, so it defaults to `0` if not specified.  If you change your `primKey` to be type `Integer`, your form won't supply a value, and therefore `primKey` will be `null`, and Hibernate will happily save the object as a new record.

Comment: So it is not possible to use persist object as model attribute & i'll have to supply dummy object & update my persist object from dummy object?

Answer (score 0):

As **@SeanAdkinson** pointed out you should change `primKey` from `int` to `Integer`.

Also you should include a **hidden field** in your form for `primKey` attribute. So that whenever there is a primKey then it is also submitted when you submit your form.

```
<form:hidden path="primKey"/>
```

Comment: Is it safe to reveal primary key as hidden attribute?

Comment: I don't think there is a `view` scope in Spring for jsp, so you will need to reveal primary key using hidden field. Your controller will be singleton only.

Comment: @NamanGala I do not think that you have to include a hidden field for the primaryKey. All the not bound values are returned as null or as default values, in this case as a 0 for the primary Key

Comment: @Diyoda, in that case it will always do insert instead of updating existing record in database if `primKey` already exist.

Comment: @NamanGala Yeah you are correct. I was only focusing on the Hibernate error, That was due to inserting the id=0 many times

Comment: @NamanGala Oh yeah. But i preferred to write separate class for binding over passing primary key as hidden field in form.

Comment: Separate class for binding, did not get you. Can you add it your question so that new people can refer it.